# Пропустят ли Alamofire в App Store

Tags: ios, launchimage, xcode7

В приложении я использую Alamofire для различных запросов. Пропустит ли приложение Apple в App Store с Alamofire? Просто я слышал, что при использовании чужих библиотек, apple не пропускает в app store. Сделал скрин как я размещаю Alamofire в своем проекте, может так будет проще понять меня + скрин когда отправляю в itunesconnect.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: делите на два вопроса. Alamofire пропустят, в нем ничего плохого нет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как уже написал в комменте:

- В использовании чужих библиотек ничего криминального нет.
- Проблема может возникнуть если библиотека использует приватные методы, которые Эпл не разрешает разработчикам использовать. Обычно при загрузке приложения в аппстор оно сразу проверяется на эти самые методы, и вы получаете предупреждение на этапе загрузки. В любом случае, библиотеки которые используют приватные методы не получают широкого распространения в сообществе, поскольку никакой пользы не несут (зачем использовать библиотеку, которая не может прийти в аппстор).

Comment: Спасибо, это было полезная для меня информация